# Communicate from custom view to activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-adapter

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
Activity -> Adapter -> Custom View
```

In the activity's layout, I have an `EditText`. In the custom view's layout, I have a `Button`. I need to make it so that when the user clicks the button in the custom view, it focuses on the `EditText` in the activity so that the user can type a message.

How can I do this?

Here is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    private List<City> cities;

    private MyAdapter adapter;

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    // The activity's EditText
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        adapter = new MyAdapter(context, cities, true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;

    private List<City> cities;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<City> cities) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public City city;

        public ViewHolder(CustomCityView itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        public void setCity(City city) {
            ((CustomCityView) itemView).setCity(city);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        CustomCityView customView = new CustomCityView(context);

        return new ViewHolder(customView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        City city = cities.get(position);

        holder.setCity(city);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cities.size();
    }
}
```

And finally, here is my custom view class:

```
public class CustomCityView extends RelativeLayout {
    private City city;

    private TextView cityName;

    // The button mentioned above
    private Button button;

    public CustomCityView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomCityView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_city_layout, this, true);

        cityName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    public void setCity(final City city) {
        this.city = city;

        cityName.setText(city.getName());

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // If the user clicks on this button, how do I focus on the activity's EditText (and pass data to it)?
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the custom view's layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The question is simple. If a user clicks on the custom view's `Button`, how can I focus on the `EditText` in the activity so that the user can type in a message?

Additionally, would it be possible to pass data from the custom view (for example, the city name from the custom layout) to the activity in order to display it as the "hint" in the activity's `EditText`?

Comment: Why do you need `CustomCityView` at all that you can't do from the `ViewHolder`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I use the `CustomCityView` in multiple situations, in different adapters, etc. Why? Is there a downside to doing it my way?

Comment: Just more classes to go through. You can use a regular XML file and a LayoutInflater if you had no custom logic in the `CustomCityView` class.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I can't do it that way since I play to add much more logic to the custom view class. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the same logic as `View.OnClickListener`...

Simply define your own interface for clicking.

Let's call it `CustomCityView.CityButtonClickListener`

```
public class CustomCityView extends RelativeLayout 
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    public interface CityButtonClickListener {
        void onCityButtonClick(City city);
    }

    private CityButtonClickListener buttonClickListener;

    public void setCityButtonClickListener(CityButtonClickListener listener) {
        this.buttonClickListener = listener;
    }

    ...
```

Then, on the regular `onClick`, call yours.

```
public class CustomCityView extends RelativeLayout 
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    ...

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                if (buttonClickListener != null) {
                    buttonClickListener.onCityButtonClick(city);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void setCity(final City city) {
        this.city = city;

        cityName.setText(city.getName());

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

You then pass that through from implementing the interface on the Activity class down into the Adapter / ViewHolder.

In other words, you can cast the Context

```
    public void setCity(City city) {
        CustomCityView cityView = (CustomCityView) itemView;
        cityView.setCity(city);
        try {
            cityView.setCityButtonClickListener( (CityButtonClickListener) context);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And back in the Activity...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements CustomCityView.CityButtonClickListener { 

    @Override 
    public void onCityButtonClick(City city) {
        // TODO: Update EditText
    }
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this. Is this "callback hell / high coupling" considered Android best programming practices? I've seen EventBus implementations for this problem as well. Which is also not perfect.

Comment: Only two levels deep of interfaces is not Callback hell. Also, interfaces / "the observer pattern" produce very loose coupling